# Android studio, library project, javadoc url setting missing

Tags: android, android-studio, javadoc

Android studio supports writing pure java modules as library. In such a library the platform jdk is used. However, the javadoc url for the documentation quickview (with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>) is wrong. Im my case for a code snippet it states on the doc for ConcurrentLinkedQueue.take()

```
Following external urls were checked:    
http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html#take()    
http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html#take
-- The documentation for this element is not found. 
Please add all the needed paths to API docs in Project Settings.
```

Where does the IDE get the javafx url from? 
How do I change that URL to a sensible default (I did not find anything in the Project Settings)?

Comment: Were you connected to the Internet when you tried this?

Comment: Yes, I had an internet connection and could access the doc in the browser manually.

Comment: check proxy settings

Comment: proxy is fine, however - as time goes by - it now (2.1.2) finds at least the correct place  `java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue` in 1.8, but still no documentation is shown, just an empty space and no link to the documentation on the Web. It seems that there is no setting to change add a doc url for general purpose Java library in Android studio - a shame regarding that the (base) IDE definitely can do that.